# How do I chain functions using move semantics?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

In the example below I want to move "a" through the functions foo and bar. Why does the address of "pp" change in the bar function? I don't understand why. I was expecting it to be the same as "tt" is in foo, which is the same as "a" is in main.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
struct A
{
    int a_;
};

template<typename T>
A foo(T &&t)
{
    auto &&tt = std::move(t);
    tt.a_ -= 3;
    std::cout << "tt=" << tt.a_ << "\t&tt=" << &tt << "\n";
    return tt;
}

template<typename T>
A bar(T &&p)
{
    auto &&pp = std::move(p);
    pp.a_++;
    std::cout << "pp=" << pp.a_ << "\t&pp=" << &pp << "\n";
    return pp;
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.a_ = 12;
    std::cout << "a=" << a.a_ << "\t&a=" << &a << "\n";
    foo(std::move(a));
    std::cout << "a=" << a.a_ << "\t&a=" << &a << "\n";
    std::cout << "function chain=" << bar(std::move(foo(std::move(a)))).a_ << "\n";
    std::cout << "a=" << a.a_ << "\t&a=" << &a << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some points:

- Moving objects still means that there are different instances which have a different address. If an instance is moved it means that its content is moved from one instance to the other in a ideally more efficient way than just copying the content. In your example, nothing is really moved but I think you are aware of that.
- You return a new instance of `A` from both `foo` and `bar`. This is where the new instances are created. You call `bar(std::move(foo(std::move(a))))` and the inner part `foo(std::move(a))` returns a new temporary. This temporary is then passed to `bar`.
- Note that `bar(std::move(foo(std::move(a))))` is unnecessary long, `bar(foo(std::move(a)))` would be sufficient as temporaries are already rvalues.

Answer (score 1):

If you think of a variable as a bucket, and a value as content contained within a bucket, then moving from one variable to another is conceptually emptying one bucket into another one.

With that in mind lets look at what you want to do:

There are two functions:

```
A f(A);
A g(A);
```

These functions both take a value and return a value, and have sideeffects.

We then have two variables:

```
A x, y;
```

and you want to do `y = g(f(x))`.  That is you want to move the value of x into the parameter of f, then move it from the return value of f, then move it into the parameter of g, then move it into y.

You can do the following:

```
A& f(A& p) { p.do_stuff(); return p; }
A& g(A& p) { p.do_stuff(); return p; }
```

making both the parameters and return types references.  This is the same way that `std::ostream` works.

Then you can use move on the final result to move it into y:

```
A x = ...;
A y = std::move(f(g(x));
```

This leaves the `x` bucket "empty" and the value after processing by f and g, in y;

Consider if you need two variables.  Perhaps you can just reuse one:

```
A x = ...;
f(g(x));
```

Here x has been mutated by f and g in-place.  In fact no move semantics are used.

You should also be familiar with something called *copy elision*, otherwise known as RVO and NRVO, which allows certain variables to share the same address (be the same bucket) in some circumstances.